# which URL should I chose for mobile?

Tags: url, mobile, seo

I was looking everywhere (as well as on Google's blog) and could not find a straight answer to this question: which URL is the best for mobile from an SEO perspective? Is there a difference between:

m.company.com
company.com/mobile
etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

m.company.com is a preferable and relatively common approach.

Comment: If word "mobile" isn't a target keyword itself so don't care about SEO and care about users.

Answer (score 0):

There's also company.mobi 
but if you really care about users, then cater for every permutation that users could try...

- m.company.mobi
- mobile.company.mobi
- wap.company.com
- wap.company.mobi
- etc
- company.com/mobile [404's should always be handled by all your domains, so directory's don't count here]